# Presentation of Heisenberg Group $\mathbb{H}$ over the field $\mathbb{F}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation

Let $\mathbb{F}$ denote the finite field. Denote $\mathbb{H}_{\mathbb{F}}=\left\{
  \left( {\begin{array}{ccc}
   1 & a & b \\
   0 & 1 & c \\
   0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right)\mid a,b,c \in \mathbb{F}\right\}$ (known as Heisenberg Group over the field $\mathbb{F}$). Could you please tell me the presentation of this group or tell me the reference which contatains the presentation.

Comment: Over prime fields, it is generated by two matrices, one whose $a$ is $1$ and the other letters zero, and the other whose $c$ is $1$ and the other letters zero. Can you see what relations you need?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez yes, you are right. Indeed the presentation of Heisenberg group over the ring $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is given in the A Presentation for the Unipotent Group over Rings with Identity by D K Biss and S Dasgupta Journal of Algebra 237, 691-707 (2001). Indeed I was wondering for the presentation of Heisenberg group over any finite field.

Answer (score 4):

If the field has order $p^n$, then you will need $2n$ generators $x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_n$, and it is probably easiest if you throw in $n$ central generators $z_1,\ldots,z_n$, where each of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, $y_1,\ldots,y_n$, and $z_1,\ldots,z_n$ are generators of the additive group of the field, and they all correspond to each other.

For relations, all generators have order $p$, and all of the $z_i$ commute with all of the $x_i$ and all of the $y_i$. Then you have, for each $i$ and each $j$, a relation $[x_i,y_j]=z_i.z_j$, where the right hand side is multiplication in the field, and you will need to calculate $z_i.z_j$ as a word in the $z_k$.

For example, for the field of order 9, using additive generators $1,w$ with $w$ a primitive element satisfying $w^2=1+w$, the $[x,y]$ commutator relation become

$[x_1,y_1]=z_1$, $[x_1,y_2]=[x_2,y_1]=z_2$, $[x_2,y_2]=z_1z_2$.

Comment: Dear Professor, I know from a very old course that if we set $A=
  \left( {\begin{array}{ccc}
   1 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right), B=\left( {\begin{array}{ccc}
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 1 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right), C=\left( {\begin{array}{ccc}
   1 & 0 & 1 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right),
$ then $H=\langle A,B,C\mid[A,B]=C,[C,A]=[C,B]=1\rangle$.

Comment: This works for the integers modulo $n$ for any $n>0$ but, for finite fields, it only works if they have prime order.

Comment: So does the $n$-th Heisenberg group over ring $\mathbb{Z}_m$ have presentation $$\big\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_n,z\,|\,[x_i,z],[y_j,z],[x_i,y_j]\!=\!z^{\delta_{ij}},x_i^m,y_i^m,z^m\big\rangle?$$ If so, what matrices do $x_i,y_j,z$ correspond to?

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that $\left|H\left(\mathbb{F}_{p}\right)\right|=p^{3}$ and $H\left(\mathbb{F}_{p}\right)$ is non-abelian, the center is a proper subgroup (Exercises~1.4.11, 2.2.14, and 5.4.20), so there are the two possibilities given by Example~5.5(7). Consider $H\left(\mathbb{F}_{2}\right)$ and let
\begin{align*}
    r
    &=
    \left(
        \begin{array}{ccc}
            1   & 1 &   0\\
            0   & 1 &   1\\
            0   & 0 &   1
        \end{array}
    \right)
    \qquad\text{and}\qquad
    s
    =
    \left(
        \begin{array}{ccc}
            1   & 1 &   0\\
            0   & 1 &   0\\
            0   & 0 &   1
        \end{array}
    \right)
\end{align*}
Observe that
\begin{align*}
    \left\langle r\right\rangle
    &=
    \left\{
        \left(
            \begin{array}{ccc}
                1   & 0 &   0\\
                0   & 1 &   0\\
                0   & 0 &   1
            \end{array}
        \right),
        \left(
            \begin{array}{ccc}
                1   & 1 &   0\\
                0   & 1 &   1\\
                0   & 0 &   1
            \end{array}
        \right),
        \left(
            \begin{array}{ccc}
                1   & 0 &   1\\
                0   & 1 &   0\\
                0   & 0 &   1
            \end{array}
        \right),
        \left(
            \begin{array}{ccc}
                1   & 1 &   1\\
                0   & 1 &   1\\
                0   & 0 &   1
            \end{array}
        \right)
    \right\}\\
    \left\langle s\right\rangle
    &=
    \left\{
        \left(
            \begin{array}{ccc}
                1   & 0 &   0\\
                0   & 1 &   0\\
                0   & 0 &   1
            \end{array}
        \right),
        \left(
            \begin{array}{ccc}
                1   & 1 &   0\\
                0   & 1 &   0\\
                0   & 0 &   1
            \end{array}
        \right)
    \right\}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
    srs^{-1}
    &=srs\\  
    &=\left(
        \begin{array}{ccc}
            1   & 1 &   0\\
            0   & 1 &   0\\
            0   & 0 &   1
        \end{array}
    \right)
    \left(
        \begin{array}{ccc}
            1   & 1 &   0\\
            0   & 1 &   1\\
            0   & 0 &   1
        \end{array}
    \right)
    \left(
        \begin{array}{ccc}
            1   & 1 &   0\\
            0   & 1 &   0\\
            0   & 0 &   1
        \end{array}
    \right)\\
    &=
    \left(
        \begin{array}{ccc}
            1   & 1 &   1\\
            0   & 1 &   1\\
            0   & 0 &   1
        \end{array}
    \right)\\
    &=r^{3}\\
    &=r^{-1}
\end{align*}
so the analogy is complete and $H\left(\mathbb{F}_{2}\right)\cong D_{8}$ (the second case of Example~5.5(7)).

On the other hand, let
\begin{align*}
    a
    &=
    \left(
        \begin{array}{ccc}
            1   & 1 &   0\\
            0   & 1 &   0\\
            0   & 0 &   1
        \end{array}
    \right)
    \qquad
    b
    =
    \left(
        \begin{array}{ccc}
            1   & 0 &   0\\
            0   & 1 &   1\\
            0   & 0 &   1
        \end{array}
    \right)
    \qquad
    c
    =
    \left(
        \begin{array}{ccc}
            1   & 0 &   1\\
            0   & 1 &   0\\
            0   & 0 &   1
        \end{array}
    \right)
\end{align*}
and observe that
\begin{align*}
    \left(
        \begin{array}{ccc}
            1   & 1 &   0\\
            0   & 1 &   0\\
            0   & 0 &   1
        \end{array}
    \right)^n
    &=
    \left(
        \begin{array}{ccc}
            1   & n &   0\\
            0   & 1 &   0\\
            0   & 0 &   1
        \end{array}
    \right)\\
    \left(
        \begin{array}{ccc}
            1   & 0 &   0\\
            0   & 1 &   1\\
            0   & 0 &   1
        \end{array}
    \right)^n
    &=
    \left(
        \begin{array}{ccc}
            1   & 0 &   0\\
            0   & 1 &   n\\
            0   & 0 &   1
        \end{array}
    \right)\\
    \left(
        \begin{array}{ccc}
            1   & 0 &   1\\
            0   & 1 &   0\\
            0   & 0 &   1
        \end{array}
    \right)^n
    &=
    \left(
        \begin{array}{ccc}
            1   & 0 &   n\\
            0   & 1 &   0\\
            0   & 0 &   1
        \end{array}
    \right)
\end{align*}
which implies $a^{p}=b^{p}=c^{p}=1$ for $a,b,c\in H\left(\mathbb{F}_{p}\right)$. Also,
\begin{align*}
    \left(
        \begin{array}{ccc}
            1   & 1 &   0\\
            0   & 1 &   0\\
            0   & 0 &   1
        \end{array}
    \right)^x
    \left(
        \begin{array}{ccc}
            1   & 0 &   0\\
            0   & 1 &   1\\
            0   & 0 &   1
        \end{array}
    \right)^y
    \left(
        \begin{array}{ccc}
            1   & 0 &   1\\
            0   & 1 &   0\\
            0   & 0 &   1
        \end{array}
    \right)^{z-xy}
    &=
    \left(
        \begin{array}{ccc}
            1   & x &   z\\
            0   & 1 &   y\\
            0   & 0 &   1
        \end{array}
    \right)
\end{align*}
and it follows that $H\left(\mathbb{F}_{p}\right)=\left\langle a,b,c\right\rangle$. In addition, it is easy to show that $\left[a,b\right]=\left[b,a\right]=c$, $ac=ca$, and $bc=cb$. Exercise~5.4.8 implies
\begin{align*}
    \left(ab\right)^{p}
    &=
    \begin{cases}
        a^{p}b^{p}\left[b,a\right]  &   p=2\\
        a^{p}b^{p}\left[b,a\right]^{\frac{p\left(p-1\right)}{2}}    &   p>2
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
so, for $p>2$ and $ab\in H\left(\mathbb{F}_{p}\right)$, $\left(ab\right)^{p}=a^{p}b^{p}c^{\frac{p\left(p-1\right)}{2}}=1$. That is, every element of $H\left(\mathbb{F}_{p}\right)$ has order $p$. It is immediate that $H\left(\mathbb{F}_{p}\right)$ is isomorphic to the first non-abelian group in Example~5.5(7). Thus the result.